# Pointing only the subdomain to another subdomain in azure

Tags: azure, dns

I have a domain say example.com and subdomain demo1.example.com hosted in azure and working fine

I want to point another subdomain paris.anotherdomain.com point to demo1.example.com in azure
while anotherdomain.com is hosted elsewhere

I think it's possible as lots of white label sites work that way but the azure support person does not know how to, says it's not possible without having to add Azure DNS Nameservers to anotherdomain.com that is currently not in Azure DNS

any pointers on what configuration is needed ?

UPDATE -
Added cname record paris at anotherdomain.com registrar which points to demo1.example.com but not working yet, getting an SSL error, removed SSL required on Azure and no go still !

config required on azure as the site uses SSL which requires adding a certificate and custom domain in azure for it to work !

Comment: You have to make a`CNAME` record in ` anotherdomain.com` zone. `paris CNAME  demo1.example.com.` Nothing to be done at Azure DNS.

Comment: What's your real purpose? If just point subdomain paris.anotherdomain.com  to demo1.example.com, you only need to create a `CNAME` record in ` `anotherdomain.com` zone. `paris CNAME  demo1.example.com.`

Comment: @NancyXiong it's a multi-tenant site, added the cname and it's not working

Comment: Could you provide more details？

Comment: the web app can host multiple sites/domains, not sure what details are required, here're some example via google https://www.google.com/search?q=which+web+app+is+multi+tenant&client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=5Ah3YNHnL6TI_QakvY3oBQ&oq=which+web+app+is+multi+ten&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoECAAQQzoFCAAQkQI6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoCCAA6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAELEDOggILhCxAxCDAToFCC4QsQM6AgguOgsILhCxAxDHARCvAToOCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQkwI6BQgAEIYDOggIABAWEAoQHjoGCAAQFhAeUNNiWOOEAWDpkgFoAXACeAKAAYcDiAGSGpIBCDE5LjMuMi4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, added an update on why azure config is required

Comment: Still no Azure config required, your SSL cert just needs to be valid for the sites you use it for. As a brief recap, the SSL cert says "here is proof that this site is named X"; if the site you wanted to visit is not X, your browser will reject the connection, as it damn well should. Anyway, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) to map a subdomain by using a CNAME record.

In this case, create a `CNAME` record in the `anotherdomain.com zone`.

```
paris CNAME  demo1.example.com.
```

Then enable HTTPS for this custom domain, refer to [Secure a custom DNS name with a TLS/SSL binding in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution to this. Wherever you have configured DNS for anotherdomain.com create a CNAME record to pointing to paris.anotherdomain.com.

Comment: Thanks, what about the azure dns setting, there needs to be something there to route it correctly right ?

Comment: Nothing required on the azure end.